# Google font appears black on iPhones, but the real color on all other devices

Tags: javascript, html, css

In my code I only adjust the font size when making the site mobile friendly.  On Android phones it appears 'normal' with the text as the color orange.  I've had this occur on Safari and Chrome on all iPhones.

Below is my entire CSS file as well as my HTML where I link the Google font, any ideas?

HTML (where I link to the google font)

```html
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Match Game</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./styles.css">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Caveat&family=Libre+Baskerville&family=Nabla&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    
</head>
```

CSS (where I declare the font-family and make adjustments for smaller screens)

```css
h1, p, #playAgain, button{
    font-family: 'Nabla', sans-serif !important;
}

@media (min-width: 319px) and (max-width: 480px) {
    h1{
        font-size: 3.5rem; 
    }


    #normal, #hard{
        font-size: 3rem;
    }

    .front{
        border-radius: 0.25rem;
    }

    .back, img{
        border-radius: 0rem;
    }

    #buttonContainer{
        margin-top: 50px;
    }
}

@media (min-width: 481px) and (max-width: 991px){
    h1{
        font-size: 5rem;
    }

    .front{
        border-radius: 0.5rem;
    }

    .back, img{
        border-radius: 0rem;
    }

    #buttonContainer{
        margin-top: 25px;
    }

    #normal, #hard{
        font-size: 3rem;
    }
}

@media (min-width: 992px){
    h1{
        margin: 0;
    }


}
```

Here is MRT:

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Nabla');
html {
  font: 80px 'Nabla';
  color-scheme: dark;
}
```

```html
Test
```

[image]

Comment: You've been on stack overflow for almost 11 years. You should know that without code there is no way we can help. Show us the code!

Comment: What sets it to orange in the first place?

Answer (score 2):

According https://caniuse.com/colr [COLR](https://css-tricks.com/colrv1-and-css-font-palette-web-typography/) support (that https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Nabla uses) was removed from Safari this September. So until Apple returns it back, such fonts will be rendered in implicit solid monochrome colour, with some luck that colour should reflect the CSS computed `color` property value.

Comment: Thanks!!!  Yeah I changed the font specifically for iPhones only because it works on iPads and all other devices.